# Pattern matching in strings

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like below :

```
<nonpublicExecutionReport>
<trade> 
</trade>
<party id="a">
    <partyId>b</partyId>
    <partyId>c</partyId>
</party>
<party id="d">
    <partyId>e</partyId>
    <partyId>f</partyId>
    <classification>g</classification>
    <country>h</country>
    <organizationType>i</organizationType>
</party>
```

What would be regular expression to fetch all party tags so the output would be following two strings  :

```
1) <party id="a">
   <partyId>b</partyId>
   <partyId>c</partyId>
   </party>
2)  <party id="d">
    <partyId>e</partyId>
    <partyId>f</partyId>
    <classification>g</classification>
    <country>h</country>
    <organizationType>i</organizationType>
</party>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some regex like this:

`<party(?:\b|>)[^>]*>[^\0]*?<\/party>`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/vI1zJ9/3)

Comment: What language are you using?